# Use addfips to add FIPS code to csv in Python

Tags: python

I am using a Python library, `addfips` to add a FIPS code to a csv that contains `state` and `county`. You can find documentation for addfips here: https://pypi.org/project/addfips/

I have imported my chosen csv successfully, as well as imported addfips successfully. I am not sure how to apply the `get_county_fips` function to iterate over every row in the csv, but I thought it might be best to use a lambda function. The lambda function appears to be working, but I am now struggling with required arguments for the `get_county_fips` function.

Here's a few lines of my csv:

```
state ,county   
AK, CITY & BOROUGH OF JUNEAU    
AK,CITY & BOROUGH OF SITKA      
WY, SWEETWATER  
WY, TETON   
WY, UINTA
```

here is my code:

```
af = addfips.AddFIPS() 
csv.apply(lambda x: af.get_county_fips(x))
```

Here is the error that's returning:

> TypeError: get_county_fips() missing 1 required positional argument: 'state'

The problem is, the csv file i'm using has multiple states, so i'm not sure what to enter as an argument. The name of the columns containing state and county are named 'state' and 'county' respectively. Can someone show me what a correct argument would look like?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please can you post a few lines of the original CSV file, along with the output of `addfips()`.  More info on creating examples is here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I see this is old but answering for future users.

I had a data frame with ~2000 entries of those only ~300 were unique locations. Instead of looping through the whole list, which can take some time, I made a FIPS data frame of the unique codes I needed and then merged (one to many). All you need is a column for state, and county. :

```
    # Dataframe for FIPS (gets all unique combinations, handles Springfield MA, Springfield IL etc.) 
    fips = pd.DataFrame(data.groupby(['State', 'County']).size().reset_index().iloc[:,[0,1]])

    # Add FIPS code to fips df
    af = addfips.AddFIPS()
    for index, row in fips.iterrows():
        fips.at[index,'FIPS']=af.get_county_fips(fips.at[index,'County'],fips.at[index,'State'])

    # Add FIPS to data
    data = fips.merge(data, how='inner', on=['County', 'State'])
```

The fips data frame will look like this:

```
>>> fips
              State     County   FIPS
0           Alabama    Autauga  01001
1           Alabama    Baldwin  01003
2           Alabama    Barbour  01005
3           Alabama       Bibb  01007
4           Alabama     Blount  01009
..              ...        ...    ...
328  South Carolina     Saluda  45081
329  South Carolina     Sumter  45085
330           Texas       Bell  48027
331           Texas  Jefferson  48245
332           Texas    Wharton  48481
```

I do recommend checking your main data frame for NaN values afterwards. I had one spelling error in my original data (LaSalle, LA instead of La Salle, La) that I didn't catch till much later.

When I put in a messier dataset with mixed countries (Spain, Canada) and some missing county values it handled it well. It just put in None type.

Answer (score 0):

The FIPS docs in your link show an example (i.e., original data file) like this -- note column labels and commas between fields.

```
state,county,statistic
IL,Cook,123
California,Los Angeles County,321
New York,Kings,137
LA,Orleans,99
Alaska,Kusilvak,12
```

Then the AddFIPS api shows this example:

```
>>> import addfips
>>> af = addfips.AddFIPS()
>>> af.get_state_fips('Puerto Rico')
'72'
>>> af.get_county_fips('Nye', state_name='Nevada')
'32023'
>>> row = {'county': 'Cook County', 'state': 'IL'}
>>> af.add_county_fips(row, county_field="county", state_field="state")
{'county': 'Cook County', 'state': 'IL', 'fips': '17031'}
```

Can you extract a FIPS identifier from the api?  If looping over the CSV file is not working as expected, consider trying one at a time, manually, and extending that.

Comment: Apologies, my csv data does have commas between values. i'm just using a visual notebook.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about the API. And my dataset is much too long to do manually.